# sticky checkbox

Tags: html, checkbox, sticky

Ii am trying to make a checkbox (to send via email) sticky.

To make sure it doesn't make a problem when sent empty I used the following:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="something" value="1">

<input type="hidden" name="something" value="0">
```

I have used things such as:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="something" value="1" <?=(($_POST['something']=='1')?'checked="checked"':'')?>>
```

But it does not work.
Can someone please help me? Many thanks Francesco

Comment: you're putting a checkbox in an email?  why?  what do you mean by sticky?

Comment: What carillonator said: what do you mean by sticky? (Generally, "sticky" means that an item stays in a particular area of the viewport - hence, a sticky footer "sticks" to the bottom of the browser window, etc.) Also, email is a text medium. Thus, html elements like checkboxes have no business in email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean `checked`?
If so then it would be

`<input type="checkbox" name="something" value="1" checked="checked" />`

Hope I understood that correctly

Comment: Your markup contradicts itself. If you're using XHTML you have to use `checked="checked"`. If you're using HTML, then the self-closing part `/>` is invalid.

Comment: My post is not showing a php code that I have inserted..don't know why

Answer (score 1):

One could interpret that *sticky* means that user cannot uncheck the checkbox. That would be achieved using `disabled="disabled"` attribute.

As a side note, however, it wouldn't be very polite to force people to subscribe to some email list...